# Flying while pregnant?

Tags: air-travel, legal, safety, pregnancy

Do all airlines have a standard policy on pregnant women flying with them?  I know of [Qantas's policies](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/conditions-carriage-full/global/en), but would I have to check every other airline to verify they're all the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did a bit of digging and found that the guidelines for airlines vary wildly so need to be checked on a per-airline basis.

A non-representative sample for single pregnancies (multiples are different again):

- [Qantas](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/conditions-carriage-full/global/en): Medical certificate with specific information required after 28 weeks, and travel allowed up to week 36 (four hour or longer flight) or week 40 (less than four hours).
- [Korean Air](http://www.koreanair.com/local/kr/gd/eng/cs/sn/eng_cs_sn_pg.jsp#1): Medical certificate issued within 72 hours of departure required after 32 weeks, and travel allowed up to week 36.
- [Air Canada](http://www.aircanada.com/en/travelinfo/before/youngtravellers/infant-child.html): Travel allowed up to week 36.  No medical certificate requirements.
- [Southwest](http://www.southwest.com/html/customer-service/family/baby-on-board-pol.html): Travel allowed up to week 38.  No medical certificate requirements.
- [Porter Airlines](https://www.flyporter.com/travel/FAQ?culture=en-CA#17): Medical certificate issued within 24 hours required after 36 weeks, and travel allowed up to 38 weeks.