# Travelling to Canada while pregnant

Tags: canada, pregnancy

I know the US can be restrictive on pregnant women travelling there unless you provide them with:

- due date
- medical insurance information
- length of time in US
- ability or plan to return home

[Source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/882/~/visit-the-u.s.-while-pregnant-and-the-risks-involved)

I can't find what kind of information, if any, would be required for entrance into Canada for a pregnant woman.  Can anyone point me to some authorative information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're not getting any answers because no such rules exist. I've travelled while pregnant-but-not-showing. I flew into the States at about 3 months, for example. I fly into the States or Canada (mostly from each other, but also from Europe, Africa, and Australia) many times a year. At no time over the past 20+ years has any paperwork or people asked me if I was pregnant or not, and I've never heard of anyone being asked for paperwork or proof of coverage, other than the airline wanting a doctor's letter for flying past 7 or 8 months. That's just mostly so they can be sure they won't have to deal with labour during the flight.

The Canadian government [information for visitors site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-who.asp) does some [arm waving](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/inadmissibility/who.asp) about how you shouldn't have a serious medical condition that would be a burden on the country, but doesn't mention pregnancy at all. It's mostly focused on not being a criminal and throws health reasons in towards the end. Everyone has to have a plan to leave and enough money to cover them during the stay.

Enjoy your visit!

Comment: I concur (I was typing up a very similar answer). As a quick search on [birth tourism](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=canada%20birth%20tourism&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=105b54f8b18d40e5&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&biw=1868&bih=1017) suggests, there is currently no problem entering Canada while pregnant. However, make sure the airline is ok with letting you fly!

Comment: @Jonas Yep, that was [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8815/1264). :)