# Insurance for travel to the USA while pregnant

Tags: usa, health, insurance, pregnancy

I'm five weeks pregnant and accompanying my husband to the USA for two months. Can I get medical insurance? If so, what companies, premiums and coverage?

Comment: People won't be able to provide information on companies, etc, unless you provide where you will be buying the insurance from.  Even then, that section may be a bit broad.

Comment: Without an indication of your country of residence, and where you're going, we can't answer companies.

Comment: One more thing to consider, many airlines don't allow pregnant women, after certain time in pergnancy, to fly. So your departure day might also be considered when you intend to return back from USA.

Comment: @DumbCoder [You're generally fine until after 28 weeks](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8815/1264), which suggests no worries here - five weeks plus the eight or nine in the USA leaves her at 14 or 15 weeks, months short of when the airlines start getting concerned.

Answer (score 8):

Having gone through this with my wife recently, yes, you can still get medical insurance.  However you will need to get in contact with the individual travel insurance providers, as some may not cover pregnancy-related issues as it is a pre-existing issue.  All will generally cover non-pregnancy-related issues.

Answer (score 4):

My UK's provider explicitly covered any non-routine medical conditions associated with pregnancy, but not the routine ones (e.g. scans, etc.). We haven't tested it luckily.

I guess you need to find a few quotes from your country, call them and ask. It also might be included in terms and conditions (it was in my case).

Answer (score 2):

Swetha has had her baby by now, but the question came up in the sidebar....

An important thing to consider when buying medical insurance is it usually covers the insured, and only the insured. Swetha was 5 weeks pregnant back in March, if she miscarries while on holiday her treatment will be covered by her insurance.

If you are >7 months and go into labor early, you may discover that your insurance will happily cover your hospital stay but will NOT cover the ICU care for your 6-weeks-premature infant, and that's going to be a LOT of money. The reason is quite simple - the policy is in the mother's name, not the child's. Can't purchase health insurance for someone who doesn't exist yet.

This happened in the late 1990s to an Alberta woman traveling to the states. The government health care back home was eventually shamed into paying the bill.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that Alberta story? I'm curious.

Comment: It happened back when mobile phones only made phone calls, the internet was a new thing and neighbors bragged about whose dial-up connection was faster. Try the Calgary Herald archives, Ralph Klein was premier at the time.